# store more than one value into a db field to be retrieved as separate values

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to store more than one value and query the database and assign each value as a separate entity?

For example, I have a database with a column `wallpaper` can I store say this into it.

wall_1.png, wall_2.png, wall_3.png

and then query the database and pull out 3 different variables that hold the wallpaper name.

so I'd have `$defaultWall = "wall_1.png"` `$wall2 = "wall_2.png"` `$wall3 = "wall_3.png"` <-- being pulled from the database.

also I have a table called settings, the user can set all their settings here. One column is for their wallpaper preference for their profile. I would like for them to have a series of uploaded wallpapers on hand if they choose to change later on. So by doing this I wanted to store an array of wallpaper urls into the db and have a tiny image preview gallery pull each wallpaper for processing and resizing from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. But more than one value in table field doesn't satisfy to the Normalization Forms.

Try to create one table with wallpapers for this row.

Comment: I have a table called settings, the user can set all their settings here. One column is for their wallpaper preference for their profile. I would like for them to have a series of uploaded wallpapers on hand if they choose to change later on. So by doing this I wanted to store an array of wallpaper urls into the db and have a tiny image preview gallery pull each wallpaper for processing and resizing.

Comment: +1, eventually the poster may want to retire/replace old wallpapers, and if they are in a separate table they can be identified by queries. If they are munged into the same column, it's a pain.

Comment: @s2xi - one table for settings, and a child table of wallpapers, where a setting can have many wallpapers? I know it seems extra work now, but it will save you time & trouble in the future :)

Comment: Alexander is right cause updating and searching this field is a difficult if not impossible work, and if it's not your case i recommend to use an XML data type instead of a simple data type.

Comment: you mean have a table to store all the wallpapers that they have, and in the settings just load up the default wallpaper they have based on what they choose off the wallpaper table?

Comment: @s2xi, yes, a table could hold all their wallpapers, with an extra column (MySQL's true/false type) to show which is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, from DDL logic, is to define another table for wallpaper images, which have foreign keys that link them to the row of that table which has the Wallpaper column in your case.

If you don't find any reason to do so, and you ARE using only PHP, use `serialize` and `unserialize` php functions to access that data from the field. You can store any data structures that way.

Comment: yes, thats what I was looking for. a serialized scenario. My problem is that when I try to store is get something like s1: s2: s3

Comment: @s2xi you are looking in the wrong direction. Don't be lame, try to listen that everyone has told you.

Comment: if you use serialization, the data will be dependent on the application which manipulates it. It may be simpler for very small applications, but as you build up more code, you'll curse yourself for not placing them in separate tables.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the expand() function in PHP!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

**Note**
I don't think this is the best way to handle such values, if you want to be able to link any amount of wallpapers (or none) to an object I would choose to use another table.

```
create table tblMain (ItemId, Name, etc)
create table tblWallpapers (WallpaperId, WallpaperName)
create table tblMainUsesWallpapers (Wallpaperid, ItemId)
```

then just select the values like so:

```
select * from tblWallpapers w
inner join tblMainUsesWallpapers muw
on w.WallpaperId = muw.WallpaperId
inner join tblMain m
on muw.ItemId = m.ItemId
where m.ItemId = x
```

Comment: i was looking at that, but the other problem is that i would also need to store more values into the field.

Comment: That should not be a problem, the split() function can return any amount of values, as long as they are separated by the same character (","). Then just loop through the array of split items

Comment: I have folloved your link and it says `Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.` Did you ever read that page yourself?

Comment: Well, try explode() then - it does the same thing http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: And if you look again, Shrapnel, I am also saying in my answer that I do not recommend that solution, but that might be beside the point of your argument.

Comment: I don't understand such kind of answers either. Can you decide - do you recommend it or not? If not - why bother to type it?

Comment: You seem like a very nice person Shrapnel! But you obviously don't believe in giving other people options?